# How to expand the %TMP% to the Full Path Name

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to replace %TMP% with the Full Path (without the ~ shorthand). How do I do this ?

If I `ECHO %TMP%`, I get `C:\DOCUME~1\{username}\LOCALS~1\Temp`.

I'd like the full path properly expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file, and use [expansion modifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx).

Specifically there's `%~f1` which is "Expands %1 to a fully qualified path name."

Example batch (we'll call it `expander.bat`):

```
@echo off
echo %~f1
```

Usage:

```
expander "%TMP%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using ancient software that requires these short paths, just disable them globally with the following: `fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 1`

Reboot and all the variables will revert to the full path.